# Create Customer Account Not working

Tags: magento2, php, customer, customer-account, magento-2.2.5

I am on `Magento 2.2.5` (issue persisted on 2.2.4 as well). I am not able to create any new customer. Whenever I try to fill in the details in NEW CUSTOMER ACCOUNT form, "customer/account/create/", the page reloads itself on clicking CREATE ACCOUNT button. I am not overriding register.phtml in my theme. Any idea on what's going on?

I had this issue on 2.2.4 but someone suggested this issue is resolved in 2.2.5 and I upgraded but the issue still persists. Please help.

PS: There are no errors in any logs.

Thanks, Sanjay

Comment: Please check in mozila browser?  Are you facing issue only google chrome?

Comment: Tested on all (Chrome, Edge, Firefox), doesn't work on anyone :(

Comment: Have you check disabling full_page_cache?

Comment: All the caches are disabled. Do I need to enable?

Comment: No,  in my cache that was cookie related issue so am asking for browser and caching but in your case it seems look liKe its different issue

Comment: surely, there is a log somewhere.. how about checking the javascript console?

Comment: Please go to your app/bootstrap.php and use error_reporting(1) then check also ctrl+u your sometimes it gives some 404 or issue on that.

Comment: Nah, didn't work... :( nothing on console as well..

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realize that my theme was overriding something in Magento_Customer module. Switched it back to Magento Luma and it worked. Now trying to figure out the real issue.

If anyone else is facing this issue, switch to basics and defaults and see if it works. It might.